# Find the coordinates of the minimum bounding rectangle enclosing two rectangles

Tags: math, geometry, pseudocode, area

Given the coordinates of the top left corners of two rectangles (`x1`, `y1`), (`x2`, `y2`), their respective widths and heights (`w1`, `h1`), (`w2`, `h2`) (They may or may not overlap). How do I find the coordinates of the top left corner (`x3`, `y3`) and the width and height (`w3`, `h3`) of the minimum bounding rectangle that encloses the 2 given rectangles. The widths and heights of the two rectangles are always parallel to the xy axis respectively. **x increases from left to right** and **y increases from top to bottom**.

For example, if 
`x1` = 2, `y1` = -1, `w1` = 3, `h1` = 6 
`x2` = -1, `y2` = 3, `w2` = 8, `h2` = 3 
then 
`x3` = -1, `y3` = -1, `w3` = 8, `h3` = 7
[image: Visualization]

I can only find `x3` and `y3` but not `w3` and `h3`. 
`x3 = min(x1, x2)`, `y3 = min(y1, y2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to define an axis-aligned rectangle is to list its four coordinates `(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`.

If you have two rectangles:

```
R1 (xmin1, xmax1, ymin1, ymax1)
R2 (xmin2, xmax2, ymin2, ymax2)
```

Then the minimum axis-aligned bounding rectangle is of course given by coordinates:

```
R (min(xmin1,xmin2), max(xmax1,xmax2), min(ymin1,ymin2), max(ymax1,ymax2))
```

You can switch easily between the `(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)` and the `(xtopleft, ytopleft, width, height)` representations:

```
(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) = (xtopleft, ytopleft, xtopleft+width, ytopleft+height)
(xtopleft, ytopleft, width, height) = (xmin, ymin, xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin)
```